# Official php-fpm docker image setup for rootless podman

Tags: php, podman

Default/official [`7.4.19-fpm`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/7.4.19-fpm/images/sha256-19e9dcc01bd64e3cb7b50909d813f5cacc96c72c5a4adc2b903902e578a0b8be?context=explore) (maybe newer images also) image of [PHP-FPM](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) runs master `php-fpm` process as `root` but single "slave" pool as hard-defined `www-data` user:

```bash
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.6  0.0 125300 30080 ?        Ss   22:48   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www-data       2  3.1  0.0 128260 21676 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data       3  4.2  0.0 128260 21648 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Because volumes are mounted by podman as owned by `root` inside the container, user `www-data` do not have full access to them (they're mostly `-rw-r--r--`).

Now, specifying user when initiating container by `--user=` makes all process run with given user:

```bash
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1000           1  1.2  0.0 125300 29888 ?        Ss   22:53   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
1000           2  1.4  0.0 128128 21488 ?        S    22:53   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
1000           3  1.4  0.0 128128 21400 ?        S    22:53   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

But this does not change mentioned problem with volume permissions.

I've spent many hours now trying to find a solution, but the best I could find is IMO dirty hacking with podman's `unshare` command on running container.

Has anyone found better way?

P.S. Bonus question: how to integrate solution nicely with `docker-compose.yml`?

---

References

- ["Using volumes with rootless podman, explained", by Tom Donohue @ 2022.11](https://www.tutorialworks.com/podman-rootless-volumes/)
- [PHP-FPM 7.4.19 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0924d69e7b856ff5fd9fded9963143a437b558b8/7.4/alpine3.16/fpm/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: [`userns=keep-id`](https://docs.podman.io/en/v4.6.1/markdown/options/userns.container.html):

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
johndoe        1  0.0  0.0 125300 29812 ?        Ss   12:40   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
johndoe        2  0.2  0.0 130176 23236 ?        S    12:40   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
johndoe        3  0.1  0.0 130484 23752 ?        S    12:40   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

**and** files on mounted volume also owned by `johndoe`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  17 johndoe johndoe      40 Dec 14 12:40 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root          4 May 12  2021 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 johndoe johndoe     275 Sep 28  2022 .babelrc
-rw-------   1 johndoe johndoe      48 Dec 14 12:40 .bash_history
```

As for `docker-compose.yml`, the relevant service must be equipped with `userns_mode: keep-id` configuration, as such:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  # PHP 7.4 running as FPM service
  php:
    image: php-fpm:7.4-fpm
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    userns_mode: keep-id
```

If anybody knows better solution - please post.